# Is it possible 9th avatar of Vishnu not happened yet?

Tags: vishnu, avatars

Some people consider the 9th avatar of Vishnu as Buddha/Balaram. Is it possible 9th avatar of Vishnu has not yet occurred yet itself? And it's unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible...

**Lord Buddha.:**

> “tataḥ kalau sampravṛtte sammohāya sura-dviṣām | buddho nāmnāñjana-sutaḥ kīkaṭeṣu bhaviṣyati ||” (SB 1:3:24).
>
> “Then, in the beginning of Kali-yuga, the Lord (Vishnu) will appear as Lord Buddha, the son of Añjanā, in the province of Gayā, just for the purpose of deluding those who are envious of the faithful theist”.